# Problem using YUI Compressor for .Net

Tags: .net, yui

I'm trying to use http://yuicompressor.codeplex.com/ which gives 2 dlls which I ref in my proj, but when I try to use it by

```
using Yahoo.Yui.Compressor
```

It gave error "The type or namespace name 'Yahoo' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?"

What is wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple sanity check things first -- I'm assuming you've added a reference to the correct assembly, right?  (your project -> references -> Add Reference, then browse to the assembly).  You didn't say which assembly you are referencing.  If that's ok, I might use a tool like Reflector to verify the namespace that exists in the referenced assembly.

If you're still running into problems, I had a similar issue where it turned out that I needed to change the "Target Framework" to be ".NET Framework 4" instead of ".NET Framework 4 Client Profile". (project properties -> application -> target framework)

Comment: wow, thank you so much for your help and yes by changing to ".Net Framework 4" got rid of the problem, what the difference between the 2 and why did it select client profile by default?

Comment: Great to hear that was the answer... For an explanation, this link will do more justice to the topic than I can:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc656912.aspx

Answer (score 0):

When I create a new project in VS 2010 and add a reference to that library, I get the same error. I also get this warning:

> The referenced assembly "Yahoo.Yui.Compressor" could not be resolved because it has a dependency on "Microsoft.Build.Framework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" which is not in the currently targeted framework ".NETFramework,Version=v4.0,Profile=Client". Please remove references to assemblies not in the targeted framework or consider retargeting your project.

By default, new .Net 4 projects target Client Profile that is missing some libraries (like ASP.NET and, apparently, `Microsoft.Build.Framework`). To fix the issue, change the target framework to “.NET Framework 4” (not Client Profile).